# Iframe navigation to http instead of https

Tags: cordova, security, iframe, navigation, winjs

I have a WinJS (for Windows 8.1) application and (without Web Host App ability) and I want to navigate to external html page.

What I thought about is, to Create an iframe with an src to the remote url, but this functionality is blocked (for security reasons).

I can allow remote urls for my application but its inly accept https urls.

I there any way to allow navigation to http instead of https as iframe src url?

- I can use it on Cordova app as well but it still has to be targeted to Windows 8.1.

Thanks

Comment: "I have to use iframe in my html in order to support appcache and indexdb - since regular webview doesn't support those features", if you use an iframe inside the webview, it's still run inside the webview and the same problems will be present

Comment: Yes, you are right. I will rephrase my question.